# Android: dynamically cycle through layout items

Tags: android, layout

Not sure if the head line describes its well, what I want is that:

I have let's say 9 TextViews in my layout, named tv1, tv2, ..., tv9.

Of course I can access each of them with

```
 TextView tv11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1)
```

Lot's of typing, so I rather would have a loop and loop through these items, but how can include the findViewbyId into a loop that I can change the value accordingly?

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason why you can't iterate over the children of the containing [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)? So you get the number of children with `getChildCount` and then you can access each individual child with `getChildAt`.

You may have to test whether a particularly child is an instance of `TextView` if you have other views in the layout, but the basic concept is fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You could make an array of the IDs you want to loop through.

IE:

```
public static final int TEXTVIEW_IDS = { R.id.tv1, R.id.tv2, R.id.tv3, etc.. };
```

In your view code:

```
for (int id : TEXTVIEW_IDS) {
  ((Textview) findViewById(id)).CallYourMethod();
}
```

If you cannot do what @James Holderness suggested, this may be a suitable alternative.